# Installing WIJMO for angular2 using NPM

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am not able to install WIJMO responsive package to my angular2 project using NPM.

I would like to know if there is any better way for doing this using a web-package.

Thanks in advance!!

Best,
Riya.

Comment: Why can't you install it? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Wijmo package through NPMImages that can be found in downloaded folder of Wijmo build or downloaded to the node_modules folder directly using following command:
npm install --save http://prerelease.componentone.com/wijmo5/npm-images/C1Wijmo-Enterprise-Eval-AMD-5.20163.259.tgz

You can also define wijmo dependency in package.json.

For more information, please refer to [wijmo documentation](http://wijmo.com/5/docs/static/angular2Components.html).

Thanks,

Manish Kumar Gupta